# GeoServer ArcGIS rasters problem

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff, jpg

My GeoServer 2.15.0 doesn't create mosaic storage using rasters created in ArcGIS (GeoTIFF, jpg). Everything is fine, when rasters created in QGIS or GlobalMapper. When I'm trying to create mosaic storage, I have an error message:

> Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file://D:\las\rer and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@7fed1e EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@4886fdb4[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@2a20c96e FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null

I'm trying to use different formats of rasters with different compression types and error still remains.

Here is GDALInfo:

> Name
>   tile0
>   Path
>   tile0.TIF
>   CRS
>   USER:100027 
>   Extent
>   3414942.1961099999025464,934141.3837400000775233 : 3418396.8961100000888109,936541.8837400000775233
>   Unit
>   meters
>   Width
>   34547
>   Height
>   24005
>   Data type
>   UInt16 - Sixteen bit unsigned integer 
>   GDAL Driver Description
>   GTiff
>   GDAL Driver Metadata
>   GeoTIFF
>   Dataset Description
>   tile0.TIF
>   Compression
>   LZW
>   Band 1
>   STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=1080,18154592972,988,766881503097,845,487802548778
>   STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
>   STATISTICS_MEAN=52,635279037621
>   STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
>   STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
>   STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
>   STATISTICS_STDDEV=32,866115467602
>   Band 2
>   STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=988,766881503097,949,88993433988,798,406154932079
>   STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
>   STATISTICS_MEAN=57,845627022763
>   STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
>   STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
>   STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
>   STATISTICS_STDDEV=30,820284462345
>   Band 3
>   STATISTICS_COVARIANCES=845,487802548778,798,406154932079,709,687473905154
>   STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=255
>   STATISTICS_MEAN=43,050365482897
>   STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
>   STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORX=1
>   STATISTICS_SKIPFACTORY=1
>   STATISTICS_STDDEV=26,639960095788
>   More information
>   DataType=Generic
>   Dimensions
>   X: 34547 Y: 24005 Bands: 3
>   Origin
>   3.41494e+06,936542
>   Pixel Size
>   0.1000000000000053901,-0.1000000000000000056

Comment: Can you run a gdalinfo on one of those files and share the output?

Comment: Here is GDALInfo

Comment: Your projection is broken by the looks of it

Comment: Sorry, but I can't open projection parameters - It is local cartesian, based on Pulkovo 42 datum.